# How to pass a custom openCV color-based image segmentation transformation to a keras CNN model?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, computer-vision

I am trying to train a Keras CNN model on plant images. I needed to preprocess those images before training because they contain extra information that I don't want the model to learn.

Solution: Color-based segmentation with openCV, I kept just the green pixels

```
def segmented(image):
    foto = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    hsv_foto = cv2.cvtColor(foto, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

    colormin=(25,50,50)
    colormax=(86,255,255)

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_foto, colormin , colormax)

    result = cv2.bitwise_and(foto, foto, mask=mask)

    return result
```

[Orignal and transformed image](https://ibb.co/hfnznYT)

**Problem:**
 The function works fine while visualizing the segmented images but I am struggling to pass it to a Keras model to train just the transformed images and not the original ones from directory while training.

**My solution:** What I am trying now is to include my **segmented()** function to the keras ImageDataGenerator:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
segmented('../input/v2-plant-seedlings-dataset/nonsegmentedv2/'),
    target_size=(64,64),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training')
```

or in training

```
training=model.fit_generator(
    segmented(train_generator),
    steps_per_epoch=100,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data = segmented(validation_generator), 
    validation_steps = 30,
    callbacks=[earlystopper1, checkpointer1]
   )
```

But I get this error that is probably related to image reading and opening

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call    last)
  <ipython-input-47-3fc9e5fcdc32> in <module>
         1 training=model.fit_generator(
   ----> 2         segmented1(train_generator),
         3         steps_per_epoch=100,
         4         epochs=20,
         5         validation_data = validation_generator,

 <ipython-input-46-24182f9d357f> in segmented1(np_image)
         1 def segmented1(np_image):
         2 
   ----> 3     foto = cv2.cvtColor(np_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
         4     hsv_foto = cv2.cvtColor(foto, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
         5 

 TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

Comment: You can apply the segmentation directly to the images in the directory.... And feed the resulting images to your model....

Comment: You have to put the function's name in you data generator. before `flow_from_directory` use keras `ImageDataGenerator`, and in setting it's parameters, put your `segmented` function as `preprocessing_function`. This source will help you with that: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Comment: you could imwrite the segmented images and use those files for training. But do you really want your network to train on a black background? Or so you want to augment all kind of random background to those samples?

Comment: @Micka Thank you for your feedback. Yes, I would like to train my network JUST on a black background. Could you please elaborate more on your 'imwrite' solution?

Comment: @Meisam Thank you for your feedback! I just edited my post and included the `ImageDataGenerator`. Could you please tell me at which line exactly I should include the **segmented()** function, I got lost in the keras documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function = segmented,
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2)
```

I didn't try your function, but here is the explanation about the input and output of `preprocessing_function`  which is mentioned in this linked: https (https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/):

> preprocessing_function: function that will be applied on each input.
>   The function will run after the image is resized and augmented. The
>   function should take one argument: one image (Numpy tensor with rank
>   3), and should output a Numpy tensor with the same shape.

You should probably modify the `segmented` function a little bit.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.